# HY00/1045 error en phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Despues de crear unas paginas y tenerlo ya diseñadas y eso, decido crear el usuario y clave para tener una db asi que creo un usuario en phpmyadmin pero cuando intento ingresar con esa cuenta me sale dicho error.

Comment: bien te voy a dejar un enlace donde vienen unos pasos a seguir donde si no te funciona uno continuas con el siguiente, no se si ya lo pudiste checar anteriormente pero sino aquí lo dejo, alguna ves me llego a servir con unos detalles que tenia al respecto, ahí viene una instrucción donde si lograron resolverlo espero y te sea de ayuda.
enlace respecto a errores con la base de datos mysql:http://www.forosdelweb.com/f86/famoso-error-1045-phpmyadmin-909318/

Comment: Aun no lo logro, MYSQL no me reconoce dicho usuario he incluso lo he creado desde la root en phpnyadmin y desde config.inc pero nads

Comment: En contestación al usuario Aprendiz , que me comentó que responder con enlaces se considera de baja calidad, respeto su opinión y quizás la manera de manejarse de este foro, se que debe ser encuanto a experiencia y si sugerí , pero si no tengo la respuesta Ami me gusta ofrecer opciones, sino es el caso pues para la próxima me reservo mejor gracias.